# Interpolating trajectory from unsorted array of 2D points where order matters

Tags: arrays, matlab, interpolation

I need a way of obtaining a Lx2 trajectory from a Nx2 array of points, i.e. a way of connecting those points into a single trajectory (for example, create a 10000x2 array of points from a 5x2 array of points). I have tried using `interp1` and `interp2` but either I don't fully understand them or they don't do what I need.

Comment: It sounds like you need `interp1`, post your code of what you tried including your input vector

Comment: what I have is `nodes = [10 10;10 20;9 50;48 6]` and I want to create a trajectory (of length 10000) that crosses those points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to be using `interp1` in a loop (i.e. to preserve original order) interpolating between each consecutive pair of points:

```
X = [10; 10.0001; 9; 48];   %// You can consider something like X = [10;10;9;48]; X=X+rand(size(X))*0.0001 instead of dealing with equal X values manually
Y = [10; 20; 50; 6];

m = 3333; %//num points between nodes
n = m*(length(X)-1);

Yi = zeros(n,1);
Xi = [];
for k = 1:length(X)-1
    xi = linspace(X(k), X(k+1), m);
    Xi = [Xi, xi];
    Yi(((k-1)*m+1):k*m) = interp1(X(k:k+1), Y(k:k+1),xi); 
end

plot(X,Y,'or');
hold on
plot(Xi,Yi);
```

To get a pentagon (not a W) try this looping code with these inputs:

```
X = [0.25; 0.75; 1; 0.5; 0; 0.25];
Y = [0; 0; 1; 1.8; 1; 0];
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This would work for the cases in which the values in X are sorted. If they are not sorted this doesn't work, but if I sort the values in X I no longer have the original points, right? I am working with a 5x2 array of random points (selected by a user) and I want to create the trajectory (of length 10000 for example) that connects those specific points

Comment: Is sorting a problem? Just re-order the Y points the same way you sorted X (either using `sortrows` or the second output of `sort`)

Comment: otherwise hmmm... you might have to call `interp1` for each pair of points you have

Comment: Sorting is kind of a problem, because the result of the interpolation is sorted in the same way. Imagine I have 5 points resembling a pentagon and I want to interpolate that pentagon by obtaining all the points in between the vertices. If I sort and then interpolate what I get is some kind of "W" because it sorts the 'x' values in ascending order and plots following those sorted values of 'x'

Comment: Try this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7233-curvspace or otherwise like I said you could do the interpolation on each pair in your original order in a loop

Comment: The interpolation on each pair in their original order in a loop gives the same result as if you sorted it beforehand (I don't know why but there it is, I guess Matlab does that by default)
I'll give the code you proposed a try, but it seems to be (from the thumbnail) that it only makes pure sinusoidal trajectories, which is not the solution I'm looking for. Thanks anyway, I'll post the solution if I come to find it

Comment: @alvaro.delaserna I have added some (untested) looping code, give it a shot, I think it should work.

Comment: Tested the new loop code and it seems to work. Just note you can't have two of the same `X` values consecutively, hence I change the second `10` to `10.0001`

Comment: @alvaro.delaserna Glad to hear it :) Please mark this as correct.