# interpolation of non monotonic data

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, interpolation

I have a question regarding the interpolation of a signal I recorded.

I have more of these signals and want to compare them. So my initial thought was to map/interpolate them on a defined interval.
I have done this before with `meshgrid()` and `griddata()`.
It worked fine, but I have a problem with 2D data.

The data looks as follow (only a small part of it):

```
y           x
-11,04  0,2301
-11,04  0,2301
-11,04  0,2301
-11,03  0,2302
-11,04  0,2302
-11,04  0,2303
-11,04  0,2303
-11,03  0,2303
-11,03  0,2303
-11,03  0,2304
```

There are really small changes because of the high sampling rate.

So in this case, I would like to map it on

```
xq=0,2301:0,0001:0,2304;
using 
interp1(x,y,xq,'method')
```

But the data isn't monotonic and I have no idea how to bypass that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702110/interpolating-trajectory-from-unsorted-array-of-2d-points-where-order-matters/21702563#21702563

Comment: Maybe you were just posting pseudo-code, but to make `xq`: `xq=0.2301:0.0001:0.2304` with dots for decimals rather than commas. Only your x data needs to be monotonic, y can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look to Nyquist sampling.  Find the smallest step in times where it changes, and make that your step size.

```
%find places where measurement changes
ind=find(diff(x)~=0)

%compute minimum y-step
dy=min(diff(y(ind)))

%create new sampling vector
y2=0.2301:dy:0.2304

%sample at that spacing
x2=interp1(x,y,y2);
```

Personally, I don't like throwing data away without a really clear reason.  If you can give more background on your project then I could feel better about justifying a different sampling approach.

EDIT:

What do you want to do with the data once it is cleaned?

I would use a spline-smooth.  Lets see if I can dig one up.

```
ft = fittype( 'loess' );
opts = fitoptions( ft );
opts.Robust = 'on';

opts.Weights = zeros(1,0);
opts.Span = 0.04;

nu=10.^linspace(-5,log10(0.5));
nu=[nu fliplr(1-nu(1:end-1))];
%plot(nu)

for i=1:length(nu)
  opts.Span=nu(i)
[fr, gof, myout] = fit( [X, Y], temp, ft, opts );
    n= myout.numobs;
    rss=gof.sse;
    k=myout.numparam;
    AIC(i)=-2*n*log(rss/n)+2*k;
end

plot(AIC)
```

And then I would pick a local minimum that wasn't an endpoint and use that as the span of interest.  That would allow me to bypass the discretization and some of the noise.  If you don't get good interior minima then you might consider adjusting the lower endpoint, turning robust off, or using AICc instead of AIC.

```
AICc (i)=-2*n*log(rss/n)+2*k+(2*k*(k+1))/(n-k-1)
```

I then might wrap the result in an function and use FPLOT to get good sampling on it.

I am, however, considered a bit of a numeric masochist and one who uses rocket launchers to shoot mosquitoes.

Comment: thats what i have been doing. but i decided on dy by myself (0.0001 is basically the minimum).
The problem is that the interp1 function doesnt work. because the data isnt monotonic


the setting is as follows. i am measuring a force displacement curve with 2400 Hz because i need the precision. but in many cases there is no change in one timestep resulting in measurements with equal value.

does this help you?

thank you so far for your time and help :D

Comment: oh, i missed this line "ind=find(diff(x)~=0)" need to try this to confirm if it solves my problem. i tried to use the function "unique" but had some problems with it

Comment: I finally had the chance to test/implement your suggestion!
It didnt solve the interpolation, but it solved the problem for me :D
i am using ind=find(diff(x)~=0) and xnew=x(ind) to get rid of the redundant data. (i dont like throwing it away either, but it seems fine so far, and i am keeping the original anyway).
for smoothing i am using savitzky golay basis functions (cause i know how to use them). but i will give your approach a try! THANK YOU