# Outline your hand with splines (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline

I'm trying to write a script so that one can put his hand on the screen, click a few points with ginput, and have matlab generate an outline of the persons hand using splines. However, I'm quite unsure how you can have splines connect points that result from  your clicks, as they of course are described by some sort of parametrization. How can you use the spline command built into matlab when the points aren't supposed to be connected 'from left to right'?

The code I have so far is not much, it just makes a box and lets you click some points

```
FigHandle = figure('Position', [15,15, 1500, 1500]);
rectangle('Position',[0,0,40,40])
daspect([1,1,1])
[x,y] = ginput;
```

So I suppose my question is really what to do with x and y so that you can spline them in such a way that they are connected 'chronologically'. (And, in the end, connecting the last one to the first one)

Comment: If you want to use linear interpolation between the points, it is very easy. Just use `plot(x,y)`. Otherwise, how do you want the line to behave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look into function cscvn

```
curve = cscvn(points)
```

returns a parametric variational, or natural, cubic spline curve (in ppform) passing through the given **sequence** points(:j), j = 1:end.

An excellent example here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/examples/constructing-spline-curves-in-2d-and-3d.html

Comment: +1 This looks like a good solution, but it requires the curve fitting toolbox. It would still be good to see an answer that doesn't need that toolbox.

Comment: Hm yes, I agree, this would work very well. I do have the toolbox myself, so this is probably a good way of doing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I've found an alternative for using the cscvn function.

Using a semi-arclength parametrisation, I can create the spline from the arrays x and y as follows:

```
diffx = diff(x);
diffy = diff(y);
t = zeros(1,length(x)-1);
for n = 1:length(x)-1 
    t(n+1) = t(n) + sqrt(diffx(n).^2+diffy(n).^2);
end
tj = linspace(t(1),t(end),300);

xj = interp1(t,x,tj,'spline');
yj = interp1(t,y,tj,'spline');
plot(x,y,'b.',xj,yj,'r-')
```

This creates pretty decent outlines.

What this does is use the fact that a curve in the plane can be approximated by connecting a finite number of points on the curve using line segments to create a polygonal path. Using this we can parametrize the points (x,y) in terms of t. As we only have a few points to create t from, we create more by adding linearly spaced points in between. Using the function interp1, we then find the intermediate values of x and y that correspond to these linearly spaced t, ti.

Comment: I got this to work, but it generated a lot of errors. `t` needs to be initialized. `(diff(x))(n).^2` is a syntax error in Matlab. But the curves do look good. If you clean up the code and add an explanation as to why it works I will award the bounty!

Comment: Hm, I apologize, that was very sloppy. It's what you get for late night answers. Now it should definitely work without too much hassle, and I added a short explanation as well.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't fully understand the line `t(n+1) = t(n) + sqrt(diffx(n).^2+diffy(n).^2);`. Could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: Yes, I'll get back to it in a bit! I have to think about how to explain it more elaborately, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length contains the gist of it. This is just an approximated form of that, as we don't have an analytic expression for x and y.

Comment: Yeah I think I've worked it out. It's just using the euclidean distance to approximate distance along the curve. The both `x` and `y` can be interpolated because the distance along the curve `t` is always monotonically increasing. It's very clever. I think it still needs a better explanation but I will award the bounty when I can (still have to wait 4 hours).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it using linear interpolation: [Interpolating trajectory from unsorted array of 2D points where order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702110/interpolating-trajectory-from-unsorted-array-of-2d-points-where-order-matters/21702563#21702563). This should get you to the same result as `plot(x,y)`.

The idea in that post is to loop through each consecutive pair of points and interpolate between just those points. You might be able to adapt this to work with splines, you need to give it 4 points each time though which could cause problems since they could double back.

To connect the start and end though just do this before interpolating:

```
x(end+1) = x(1);
y(end+1) = y(1);
```

Comment: Actually I don't think you can extend this to splines so easily... but it will work for linear interpolation which is a start

Comment: A sequence of more than 3 points may not have a direction in which they are monotone. Hence I think this is a dead end. Of course the general idea of taking four points, and using them to determine what the line between the middle points should look like is valid, but I don't see a straightforward way to do this.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I agree. I'm very interested to know what algorithm `cscvn` uses.